# \xi latex style gives invalid \x escape in python

Tags: python, latex

I am plotting in Python using Geany, but when I try to label my axis with say `$ \xi$` i.e. the greek letter xi, I get the

> invalid \x escape

error. This does not happen for any other greek letter. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python strings, `\x` indicates a hexadecimally escaped character, such as `'\x7a'`, which is the same as `'z'`, because the ASCII code of `'z'` is `7a` in hexadecimal. You have to escape the backslash into `\\` (your resulting string would look like `"$\\xi$"`) or use *raw strings* (`r"$\xi$"`) where the escapes are (mostly) ignored.

The official docs provide a [list of escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a raw string: `r"$ \xi$"` which will not treat the `\x` as an escape for a  unicode char.

Or, you could escape the slash: `"$ \\xi$"`

It doesn't happen with other greek letters you've tried because they don't happen to start with a character used as a control code. But if you tried "\rho" I imagine you might be surprised, as "\r" is a carriage return code.

There are [various such codes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), including `\b, \t, \n, \a, \r, \u, \v, \f, \x, \U`